# check if any values are in a range

Tags: r, apply

For a set of observations I have dates of response events.

```
structure(list(Date1_P2 = structure(c(14061, 14944, 14944), class = "Date"), 
    Date2_P2 = structure(c(NA, 11566, 11747), class = "Date"), 
    Date3_P2 = structure(c(NA, 10408, 11627), class = "Date"), 
    Date4_P2 = structure(c(NA, 8370, 11566), class = "Date")), .Names = c("Date1_P2", 
"Date2_P2", "Date3_P2", "Date4_P2"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
> dates
    Date1_P2   Date2_P2   Date3_P2   Date4_P2
1 2008-07-01       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
2 2010-12-01 2001-09-01 1998-07-01 1992-12-01
3 2010-12-01 2002-03-01 2001-11-01 2001-09-01
```

I want to create a variable that is `TRUE` if any of these dates falls within a range of a triggering event. Say, something happened in September 2001 that the observations could have responded to or anticipated. I have written the following function,

```
checkmove <- function(event, range, moves){
  moves <- as.numeric(moves)
  early <- as.numeric(event - range)
  late  <- as.numeric(event + range)
  moved <- any(moves > early & moves < late, na.rm=TRUE) 
  return(moved)
}
```

If there is a response within 180 days on either side of the event, the value should be `TRUE`. The function works line by line, but I can't get it to work on the full table.

```
# This is right
> checkmove(as.Date("2001-09-01"), 180, dates[1,])
[1] FALSE
> checkmove(as.Date("2001-09-01"), 180, dates[2,])
[1] TRUE
> checkmove(as.Date("2001-09-01"), 180, dates[3,])
[1] TRUE
# This is wrong
> apply(dates, 1, function(x) checkmove(as.Date("2001-09-01"), 180, x))
    1     2     3 
FALSE FALSE FALSE 
Warning messages:
1: In checkmove(as.Date("2001-09-01"), 180, x) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
2: In checkmove(as.Date("2001-09-01"), 180, x) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
3: In checkmove(as.Date("2001-09-01"), 180, x) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

Am I not using the right `apply` function? I'd really rather avoid a `for` loop. Is there a better way to go about this to begin with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `apply` coerces the data frame `dates` in class  `matrix`. so the values are not any more of class `date` but `character`. Therefore  `as.numeric` does "not" work (NAs introduced by coercion).

```
> dates
    Date1_P2   Date2_P2   Date3_P2   Date4_P2
1 2008-07-01       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
2 2010-12-01 2001-09-01 1998-07-01 1992-12-01
3 2010-12-01 2002-03-01 2001-11-01 2001-09-01
> apply(dates, 1, function(x) class(x))
          1           2           3 
"character" "character" "character"
```

Try with "ddply" family in package `plyr`. For example

```
> library(plyr)
> aaply(dates, 1, function(x) checkmove(as.Date("2001-09-01"), 180, x), .expand=F)
    1     2     3 
FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: Excellent. I feel that the schism between the `base` and `plyr` apply functions is one of the biggest hurdles in R.

Comment: @gmacfarlane plyr function are more "user friendly" (in particular for providing several choices in input/output data type). If a "base" solution is needed/wanted then you have: 1) for loop, 2)conversion to numeric before `apply`, 3) conversion to dates then back to numeric inside `apply` (this will be slower but still a valid option)